# Chromium/Electron simultaneous multi-touch not working after 10 touches

Tags: google-chrome, electron, touch, chromium, multi-touch

Chrome/Electron not reporting more than 10 simultaneous touch points. Developing electron application.

I have a display that supports upwards of 20 touches. I am using electron to develop an application and touches dont seem to work after exceeding 9/10 simulataneous touches. Is there any resource on how to increase that limit in chrome or in electron applications?

Currently using Electron v24.3.1 (latest) it has chrome/chromium version 112.0.5615.183 and Node 18.14.0 Windows 10 Pro 22H2